# ctrl+c and ctrl-z not working in ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, sshd, ctrl

I have opened a ssh session to remote computer using

```
ssh root@<ip>
```

I tried to run some program on remote machine. e.g.

```
tail -f /var/log/log.txt
```

But when i press `ctrl-c` or `ctrl-z` that program is not killed/suspended. I couldn't able to get control out of that process in terminal.

Comment: @Bungicasse tried that now, still not able to kill

Comment: Does the `tail -f` continue to output data? It may be that the terminal session crashes (either some sort of remote timeout or pipe issue)

Comment: @stuts yes tail is still running. If i login to another session and kill tail, i can access the terminal

Comment: What OS are the source and destination systems? Does this problem effect all user accounts? I'm wondering if there could be a custom terminal/shell profile or something that overrides shortcuts on the destination system.

Comment: @stuts source is redhat linux and destination is QNX PPC. telnet session is working properly

Comment: What kind of system is the QNX PPC? Does it work when you try Ctrl-Break (the Pause/Break key)? Do the suspension/resume keys work (Ctrl-S & Ctrl-Q)? Do you have the latest version of the OS installed (may be a bug in a package)? Has the handler for ctrl-c been changed ([see this forum post](http://www.openqnx.com/phpbbforum/viewtopic.php?t=3287))?

Comment: I am sure there is no change in signal handler, otherwise Ctrl-c in telnet session wouldn't have worked. also instead of `tail` this time i tried `cat>newfile with Ctrl-c in ssh session`, it is not working but working as expected in telnet session. @stuts

Comment: Do you provide any arguments to your ssh command? Could you try `-t` argument to `ssh` as this should forward the raw ctrl-c to the server.

Comment: @stuts `ssh -t` is also not working. One more thing i noticed is in terminal(ksh) if I press ctrl-c cursor moves and Ctrl-D close the session but in foreground process it is not taking the Ctrl-c or Ctrl-d

Comment: Is that on the client or the server? Do you see `^C` print to the terminal?

Comment: I encounter the same issue. Now I have to using the following commands to terminate the tail process

`ctrl - z` then
`kill %1`